# RangeError maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, latitude-longitude

For a school project i'm working a nodejs application.
I need to submit some locations of random pokemon. At this moment i'm using dummy data but i'm already getting errors.

I submit to a maximum of 10 locations to mongodb using mongoose but get the following error:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

The data is valid to the mongoose Schema. The error is shown also when i submit just 1 location (as it own, not included in a array).

```
{ _id: 5702bcc7698a36c82833a943,
  name: 'Pikachu',
  pid: 0,
  lng: 5.298302246195419,
  lat: 51.68774273818562 }.
```

My code looks like this:

```
var startDate = new Date();

if (!req.query.lat || !req.query.lng){
    res.status(400).json("Your location has not been included");
}

var lat = parseFloat(req.query.lat);
var lng = parseFloat(req.query.lng);

location.find({}).exec(function(err, locations){
    if (err){ return next(err); }

    var filteredlocations = [];
    locations.forEach(function(fetchedLocation) {
        distance = calcDistance(fetchedLocation.lat, fetchedLocation.lng, lat, lng);
        if (distance < 1000){
            filteredlocations.push(fetchedLocation);
        }
    });

    if (filteredlocations.length < 10) {
        var toAdd = 1 - filteredlocations.length;

        var newlocations = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < toAdd; i++){
            var randomlocation = randomLocation(lat, lng);

            var newlocation = new location({
                "lat": randomlocation.lat,
                "lng": randomlocation.lng,
                "pid": 0,
                "name": "Pikachu",
            });

            newlocations.push(newlocation);
        }

        console.log(newlocations[0]);
        location.collection.insert(newlocations[0], onInsert);
        function onInsert(err, docs){
            if (err){
                console.log("err: " + err);
            } else {
                filteredlocations.push(docs);
                res.json(filteredlocations);
            }
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Call stack size is a recusion problem -- there is no recursion in the code you have posted -- you need to post a better example of your problem

Comment: I have edited the main topic with the full code. hope that will helps. Both functions calcDistance and randomLocation use a return statement in case that is relevant.

Comment: `var toAdd = 1 - filteredlocations.length;` ???